# Code scrolling lags in LiClipse 4.4 with the latest PyDev

Tags: pydev, liclipse

I disabled Overview Ruler Minimap and enabled vertical scrollbar.
When I scroll code using scrollbar caret or using mouse wheel, scrollbar and line numbers are scrolled immediately and smoothly. But the code is not scrolled at all and then instantly jumps to new position in 1-2 seconds

I use the latest LiclipSe 4.4 on Windows 8.1 wit Python 3.6.3

So maybe some settings can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in slow system speed
I upgraded my computer (Core i5 7600K instead of AMD FX-8320) and the bug disappeared

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the scrollbar theming. Eclipse started doing some operations asynchronously (which is good for non-windows platforms) but the asynchronous paint is taking more time than it should on Windows (so, this must be fixed in Eclipse itself).

Until that's fixed, the workarounds are turning off the themed scrollbar or using the overview ruler minimap and hiding the scrollbar.

Comment: So if I disable themed scrollbar, the default scrollbar will be used and all will be work ok, right? How to do it?

Comment: It seems like you're wrong. I found the checkbox "Apply scrollbar theming customization to StyledText editors?" and unchecked it. It didn't help.

Comment: When you did that, did the scrollbars become unthemed? (I think you may need to restart after changing that setting too)

Comment: I am not sure, because I use light theme, so the scrollbar is always look like windows default

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I attached screenshot to main post, please look. Btw, only vertical scrollbar is buggy, but horisontal works smoothly

Comment: It's using the native scrollbar, so, the issue is not really what I expected (I can't reproduce the behavior you're having). I have to take a deeper look on SWT itself to check for a possible culprit. So, please report this as a bug (as a note, this is the first report I have for this behavior and unfortunately I don't have a workaround right now).

Comment: Finally the problem was solved by changing hardware. AMD FX 8320 +  16Gb DDR3 + MB Asrock 880GM-LE was not enough, but width Core i5-7600K + 16Gb DDR4 + MB Gigabyte Z170X Gaming 7 is enough to scroll without this lag. All other hardware and softwary were not changed (the same OS installation). But anyway it is very strange that this requires such powerful hardware like top 3D game or similar heavy software:)